# Getting a PropertyInfo.Name from a FieldInfo object

Tags: c#, reflection, xamarin.forms, propertyinfo, fieldinfo

I have a method which uses some FieldInfo objects:

```
public static T SetFieldValue<T>(this T src, string propName, object value)
            {
                Type type = typeof(T);
                FieldInfo propInfo = type.GetField(propName, 
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                Type propType = propInfo.FieldType;
                var targetType = IsNullableType(propType) 
                    ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propType) : propType;
                value = Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);
                propInfo.SetValue(src, value);
                return src;
            }
```

Now I need some way of getting a PropertyInfo object from a specific FieldInfo this function returns, mainly because I specifically need the PropertyInfo.Name string, any thoughts on that?

Edit: 
Here's some more specific code, I use this method to get the difference between two objects:

```
public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<T>(this T val1, T val2)
        {
            List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
            FieldInfo[] fi = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            foreach (FieldInfo f in fi) {
                Variance v = new Variance();
                v.Prop = f.Name;
                v.valA = f.GetValue(val1);
                v.valB = f.GetValue(val2);
                if (v.valA != null) {
                    if (!v.valA.Equals(v.valB))
                        variances.Add(v);
                } else if (v.valB != null) {
                    variances.Add(v);
                }
            }
            return variances;
        }
```

Then I use the returned fields to format a SQL query which I'll send to a webservice, to be more specific. But the FieldInfo.Name objects are generally something like k__BackingField or k__BackingField
I need the PropertyInfo.Name, which is the correct name.
Is there some way to create a PropertyInfo object from a FieldInfo object?

Answer (score 0):

i got this in my old codes.

```
    private static PropertyInfo GetInfo(object myObject, string name)
    {
        return myObject.GetType().GetProperty(name);
    }
```

you can use PropertyInfo

msdn
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2

and if you want get all members in T

```
            Type type = typeof(T);
            MemberInfo[] tempInfo = type.GetMembers();
```

MemberInfo
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Saddly I necessarily need the FieldInfo so I can't change that method ('cause I need to set values on the fields at runtime), unless you can show me a way to set the property value of a object using PropertyInfo. I actually already use a function exactly like your GetInfo, I'll increment my question with more code so you can understand the case.

Answer (score 0):

I made my way around it:

```
public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<T>(this T val1, T val2, bool pName = false)
        {
            List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
            FieldInfo[] fi = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            foreach (FieldInfo f in fi) {
                Variance v = new Variance();
                PropertyInfo prop = default(PropertyInfo);
                if (pName) {
                    prop = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => f.Name.Contains(p.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                v.Prop = pName ? (prop != default(PropertyInfo) ? prop.Name : "") : f.Name;
                v.valA = f.GetValue(val1);
                v.valB = f.GetValue(val2);
                if (v.valA != null) {
                    if (!v.valA.Equals(v.valB))
                        variances.Add(v);
                } else if (v.valB != null) {
                    variances.Add(v);
                }
            }
            return variances;
        }
```

What I did is giving the possibility of this method returning the PropertyInfo.Name.